# Two Queries take < 15s Each, but Combined Take 10min?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, sqlperformance

I have a large query that I'm trying to optimize.  I've broken sections down and have been evaluating them and improving the performance with help from the community.

I have two queries, I'll call them City and State.  The City query takes 3-4s to run on 15,737 records.  The State query takes 12s on the same records.  But when I combine them they take 10m 46s.

I believe I have identified where the Combined Query (below) is getting hung up, but I don't know why, or how to fix it.

[City Query Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B14z2KOyF)

```
-- 15,737 Records: 4s
SELECT
    uc.[Company],
    uc.[VendorID],
        
    CASE
        -- Populated and Confirmed; Return City Untouched
        WHEN ( uc.[City] IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS( SELECT [City] FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo] WHERE [City] = uc.[cleanCity] ) )
            THEN uc.[cleanCity]  -- Data Confirmed, Return City Untouched


        -- Attempt to determine from State, Zip, Country
        WHEN ( fn_City.[City] IS NOT NULL)
            THEN fn_City.[City]  -- Match Found; Return Match

        -- No Match Found
        ELSE uc.[City]
    END AS [City]
        
    FROM [Ultra_Cleansed_Vendors_Assist-test] uc
    OUTER APPLY [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, NULL, uc.[State], uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) fn_City
ORDER BY [Company], [VendorID]
```

[State Query Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByJBb5d1F)

```
-- 15,737 Records: 12s
SELECT 
    uc.[Company],
    uc.[VendorID],

    CASE
        -- Populated and Confirmed; Return State Untouched
        WHEN ( uc.[State] IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS( SELECT [state_abbr] FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo] WHERE [state_abbr] = uc.[State] OR [state_long] = uc.[State]) )
--          THEN 'Confirmed'
            THEN ( SELECT TOP(1) [state_abbr] FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo] WHERE [state_abbr] = uc.[State] OR [state_long] = uc.[State] ORDER BY [state_abbr] )  -- Data Confirmed, Return City Untouched


        -- Attempt to determine from State, Zip, Country
        WHEN ( fn_State.[state_abbr] IS NOT NULL)
            THEN fn_State.[state_abbr]  -- Match Found; Return Match

        -- No Match Found
        ELSE uc.[State]
    END AS [State]
        
    FROM [Ultra_Cleansed_Vendors_Assist-test] uc
    OUTER APPLY [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], NULL, uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) fn_State
ORDER BY [Company], [VendorID]
```

Combining the two then takes 10m 46s.  I tried adding the `OUTER APPLY` for fn_City (not the CASE expression) to the State Query and it only increase the runtime by 2s, so that doesn't appear to be the issue.  It appears to be hung up on the first `WHEN` in the State `CASE` expression.  If I remove that WHEN it runs in 7s, and if I change the `THEN` to `THEN 'Confirmed'` it takes 1m 3s, so seems that the entire `WHEN` is an issue, and the `THEN` is a big one.

[Combined Query Execution Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SytBH9dkK)

```
-- 15,737 Records: 10m 46s
SELECT 
    uc.[Company],
    uc.[VendorID],

    CASE
        -- Populated and Confirmed; Return City Untouched
        WHEN ( uc.[City] IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS( SELECT [City] FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo] WHERE [City] = uc.[cleanCity] ) )
            THEN uc.[cleanCity]  -- Data Confirmed, Return City Untouched


        -- Attempt to determine from State, Zip, Country
        WHEN ( fn_City.[City] IS NOT NULL)
            THEN fn_City.[City]  -- Match Found; Return Match

        -- No Match Found
        ELSE uc.[City]
    END AS [City],

    CASE
        -- Populated and Confirmed; Return State Untouched
        WHEN ( uc.[State] IS NOT NULL AND EXISTS( SELECT [state_abbr] FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo] WHERE [state_abbr] = uc.[State] OR [state_long] = uc.[State]) )
            THEN ( SELECT TOP(1) [state_abbr] FROM [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo] WHERE [state_abbr] = uc.[State] OR [state_long] = uc.[State] ORDER BY [state_abbr] )  -- Data Confirmed, Return City Untouched


        -- Attempt to determine from State, Zip, Country
        WHEN ( fn_State.[state_abbr] IS NOT NULL)
            THEN fn_State.[state_abbr]  -- Match Found; Return Match

        -- No Match Found
        ELSE uc.[State]
    END AS [State]
        
    FROM [Ultra_Cleansed_Vendors_Assist-test] uc
    OUTER APPLY [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, NULL, uc.[State], uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) fn_City
    OUTER APPLY [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], NULL, uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) fn_State
ORDER BY [Company], [VendorID]
```

Table Definitions and Indexes

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Ultra_Cleansed_Vendors_Assist-test] (
    [Company]   [varchar](255) NULL,
    [VendorID]  [varchar](255) NULL,
    [City]      [varchar](255) NULL,
    [State]     [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Zip]       [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Country]   [varchar](255) NULL,
    [cleanCity] [varchar](255) NULL
)


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CityStateInfo] (
    [City]          [varchar](255) NULL,
    [State_abbr]    [varchar](10) NULL,
    [State_long]    [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Zip]           [varchar](20) NULL,
    [County]        [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country]       [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Longitude]     [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Latitude]      [varchar](15) NULL,
    [StateFIPS]     [varchar](10) NULL,
    [CountryFIPS]   [varchar](10) NULL,
    [TimeZone]      [int] NULL,
    [cleanCity]     [varchar](255) NULL,
    [Country_abbr]  [varchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_CITY]            ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([City] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_cleanCity]       ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([cleanCity] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_City_Zip]        ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([City] ASC, [Zip] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_City_State]      ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([City] ASC, [State_abbr] ASC, [State_long] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_City_State_Zip]  ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([City] ASC, [State_abbr] ASC, [State_long] ASC, [Zip] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_STATE_LONG]      ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([State_long] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_STATE_ABBR]      ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([State_abbr] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_State_Zip]       ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([State_abbr] ASC, [State_long] ASC, [Zip] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_ZIP]             ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([Zip] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_COUNTY]          ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([County] ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [NCI_COUNTRY]         ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([Country] ASC)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [CI_City_State_Zip_Country] ON [dbo].[CityStateInfo] ([Country] DESC, [State_long] ASC, [State_abbr] ASC, [City] ASC, [Zip] ASC)
```

Comment: Execute your 2 queries separately storing the results into temp tables. Then have a final query which joins to the 2 temp tables. Sometimes with more complex queries SQL Server can get confused.

Comment: @DaleK  Ok, I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing something completely ass-backwards or missed something obvious.  I did those 2 queries, and 2 others and combined them.  It takes 19-23 seconds to run :D

Comment: You still might be :) its possible you could be missing indexes or similar. But the fact that each query performs OK on its own suggests SQL Server overcomplicated it.

Comment: It seems possible to substitute LEFT JOIN for the correlated subquery contained in the CASE logic (which is likely the issue).  It could take a few tries to get tho

Comment: Your second query could do with an `OUTER APPLY` for `CityStateInfo`. Creating a load of single column indexes is pointless, as you can see from the query plans. Instead create one index with the keys you need and include other columns eg `[Ultra_Cleansed_Vendors_Assist-test] (Company, VendorID) INCLUDE (City, State, Zip, Country, cleanCity)`

Answer (score 0):

the following queries attempt to efficiently replicate the logic.  The correlated subqueries (using EXISTS) are extracted into `LEFT JOIN`(s) and `COALESCE` function(s).  Maybe something like this

```
/* first query */
SELECT
    uc.[Company],
    uc.[VendorID],
        
    coalesce( csi.[City], fn_City.[City], uc.[City]) [City]

FROM [Ultra_Cleansed_Vendors_Assist-test] uc
     left join [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo] csi on uc.[cleanCity] = csi.[City]
     OUTER APPLY [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, NULL, uc.[State], uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) fn_City
ORDER BY [Company], [VendorID];

/* second query */
SELECT 
    uc.[Company],
    uc.[VendorID],

    coalesce( csi.[state_abbr], csi.[state_long], fn_State.[state_abbr], uc.[State]) [State]
 
FROM [Ultra_Cleansed_Vendors_Assist-test] uc
     left join [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo] csi on uc.[State] = csi.[state_abbr]
                                                    or uc.[State] = csi.[state_long]
     OUTER APPLY [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], NULL, uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) fn_State
ORDER BY [Company], [VendorID];

/* combined */ 
SELECT 
    uc.[Company],
    uc.[VendorID],
    coalesce( csi.[City], fn_City.[City], uc.[City]) [City],
    coalesce( csi.[state_abbr], csi.[state_long], fn_State.[state_abbr], uc.[State]) [State]
 
FROM [Ultra_Cleansed_Vendors_Assist-test] uc
     left join [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo] csi on uc.[cleanCity] = csi.[City]
     left join [ULTRA].[dbo].[CityStateInfo] csi on uc.[State] = csi.[state_abbr]
                                                    or uc.[State] = csi.[state_long]
     OUTER APPLY [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, NULL, uc.[State], uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) fn_City
     OUTER APPLY [ULTRA].[dbo].[fn_LocationInfo](0, uc.[cleanCity], NULL, uc.[Zip], uc.[Country]) fn_State
ORDER BY [Company], [VendorID];
```

Comment: I thought the same, but it won't work.  `[CityStateInfo]` contains every City, State and Zip in the US and Canada.  So there can be dozens of matches for a single City and you end up with a whole lot of duplication/extra rows.  Even more at the State level.

Comment: @Dizzy49 I made an attempt.  We're supposed to propose complete answers.  As mentioned in the comments above my answer assumed a lot and maybe it takes a few iterations to get it right.  It seems the next step would be to dedupe CityStateInfo (twice) so the JOINs are on unique key(s)?